# WordPress - Add HTML message to existing metabox

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add some text to an existing metabox in WordPress. I have this so far...

```
add_filter( 'post_slug_meta_box', 'custom_slug_msg' );
function custom_slug_msg( $content ) {
  $content = 'test';
  return $content;
}
```

This is modifying the input value of the slug itself, I am trying to add some html instructions above instead.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve it?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but if you want to add text to the metabox, you can try to use the label container:

```
add_filter( 'post_slug_meta_box', 'custom_slug_msg' );
function custom_slug_msg( $content ) {
  $content = 'test';
  return $content;
<label>text</label>
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any documentation on this filter hook.